# Issue with aligning two DIV's horizontally

Tags: css, html

I have searched countless threads with the same issue, yet they do not seem to work for my case.
I am trying to completed a section of my website where there are 3 little box's each which contain an image in the top half and then text in the bottom. The problem is when i float one to the right, in order to ensure that it ends up horizontally positioned, it moves to the right, although it does not move up alongside the other.

Here is part of my code, which is relevant to the divs.

CSS:

```
#features {
background:yellow;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-top: 50px;
height: 400px;
}

#features .section2 {

margin: 0 auto;
background: blue;
width: 960px;
height: auto;

}

#column_1 {
background: orange;
width: 290px;
}

#column_1 .index-icon {

 width: 290px;
}

#column_1 .index-icon img.news_image {

margin-left: 103px;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
}

#column_1 .text {

padding-top: 30px;
}

#column_1 .text h4 {

text-align: center;
}

#column_1 .text p {

font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
color: #659EC7;
} 

#column_2 {
width: 290px;
background: pink;
}


#column_2 .index-icon img.news_image {

margin-left: 103px;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
}

#column_2 .text {

padding-top: 30px;
}

#column_2 .text h4 {

text-align: center;
}

#column_2 .text p {

font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
color: #659EC7;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="features">

    <div class="section2">

            <div id="column_1">
                <div class="index-icon"><img class="news_image" src="images/mail.png"></div>
                <div class="text">

                    <h4> NEWS </h4>

                    <p> We're not just great Photoshoppers also have experience developing products as entrepreneurs. This allows us to contribute to your project beyond just the design. </p>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="column_2">
                <div class="index-icon"><img class="news_image" src="images/mail.png"></div>
                <div class="text">

                    <h4> NEWS </h4>

                    <p> We're not just great Photoshoppers also have experience developing products as entrepreneurs. This allows us to contribute to your project beyond just the design. </p>

                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Thanks alot for any responses with this issue

Comment: is this what you want? http://fiddle.jshell.net/CkxkN/1/show/

Comment: Some will throw stones at me for proposing `<table>` with `border="0"` but it's easy to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this CSS:

```
#features {
    background:yellow;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 400px;
}
#features .section2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
}
#column_1 {
    background: orange;
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
}
#column_1 .index-icon {
    width: 290px;
}
#column_1 .index-icon img.news_image {
    margin-left: 103px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}
#column_1 .text {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#column_1 .text h4 {
    text-align: center;
}
#column_1 .text p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #659EC7;
}
#column_2 {
    width: 290px;
    background: pink;
    float: right;
}
#column_2 .index-icon img.news_image {
    margin-left: 103px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}
#column_2 .text {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#column_2 .text h4 {
    text-align: center;
}
#column_2 .text p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #659EC7;
}
```

Just added `float: left;` to `#column1` and `float: right;` to `#column2` :)

[Fiddle.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CkxkN/1/show/)

Comment: thanks alot for the reply, will try your method and get back to you ASAP :) Thanks

Comment: Hhahahhaha, it worked! Thank you very much. I tried that before and it didnt want to work. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is quite common and it actually has an easy way to fix it.

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hECT6/1/) I added a class to each of your columns so I could set their common CSS at once.

The trick is use the CSS attribute `display` to change how a specific component is displayed in the page flow.

For example a `span` tag is usually displayed `inline` meaning consecutive `span` tags will keep in the same line.

On the other hand `div` tags are displayed as `block` by default which means they take a new line each.

If you want one or more div to be displayed in the same line simply add `display:inline;` to its CSS.

In the example fiddle I used `display:inline-block;` which is slighlty different but pretty much the same as `display:inline;`

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) is the detailed explanation of the attribute `display`

Hope this helps